# How to repeat code in JavaScript Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, reddit

I'm making a discord bot that gets a random post from Reddit (r/CuteAnimeGirls)
and sends the image link to the discord server. But because not every post on Reddit is
an image some links do not work. I filter out those links by checking if the url ends with .png / .jpg / .gif if it does I send the link to the server. If I get a *not working* link I want to repeat the process and search for a differnt Post until I find a working link.
This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const api = require("imageapi.js");

var endings = [".png", ".jpg", ".gif"]

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content === '%animegirl') {
            
        let subreddits = ["CuteAnimeGirls"];        
        let subreddit = subreddits[Math.floor(Math.random()*(subreddits.length))];
        var legal = false;                            
            
        api(subreddit).then((img) => {                            
            console.log(img)
                
            for (var i = 0; i <= endings.length; i++){
                    
                if (img.endsWith(endings[i])) {                        
                    legal = true;
                    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`A cute anime girl`)
                    .setURL(`https://www.reddit.com/r/CuteAnimeGirls`)
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    .setImage(img)
                    message.channel.send(Embed)
                    break;
                }
            }
                
            if (legal === false){
                console.log('Invalid URL')
            }

        })
    }
});

client.login("token")
```

I have tried a while loop but I got following error:

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code, it's faster and cleaner:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const api = require("imageapi.js");

const legalExtensions = [".png", ".jpg", ".gif"]

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content === '%animegirl') {
            
        let subreddits = ["CuteAnimeGirls"];        
        let subreddit = subreddits[Math.floor(Math.random()*(subreddits.length))];                           
            
        api(subreddit).then((img) => {

            let legal = legalExtensions.some((ext) => img.endsWith(ext)); 
                
            if (legal)
                const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`A cute anime girl`)
                    .setURL(`https://www.reddit.com/r/CuteAnimeGirls`)
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    .setImage(img)
                message.channel.send(Embed)
            } else {
                message.channel.send('Invalid URL');
            }

        })
    }
});

client.login("token")
```